# Hierarchical (categorical) data to tree plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tree, cluster-analysis, taxonomy

**Data** 
I have the following (simplified) dataset, we call `df` from now on:

```
                     species    rank                   value
1           Pseudomonas putida  family        Pseudomonadaceae
2       Pseudomonas aeruginosa  family        Pseudomonadaceae
3  Enterobacter xiangfangensis  family      Enterobacteriaceae
4          Salmonella enterica  family      Enterobacteriaceae
5        Klebsiella pneumoniae  family      Enterobacteriaceae
6           Pseudomonas putida   genus             Pseudomonas
7       Pseudomonas aeruginosa   genus             Pseudomonas
8  Enterobacter xiangfangensis   genus            Enterobacter
9          Salmonella enterica   genus              Salmonella
10       Klebsiella pneumoniae   genus              Klebsiella
11          Pseudomonas putida species      Pseudomonas putida
12      Pseudomonas aeruginosa species  Pseudomonas aeruginosa
13 Enterobacter xiangfangensis species Enterobacter hormaechei
14         Salmonella enterica species     Salmonella enterica
15       Klebsiella pneumoniae species   Klebsiella pneumoniae
```

---

**What I want to achieve**

This data is [taxonomy data](https://www.britannica.com/science/taxonomy) that shows the `species` classification, where the `rank` is in order of family > genus > species. Due to the hierarchical nature I want to show this as a tree, preferentially in `ggplot2` like so:
[image]

---

**What I tried**
While I found a package, `taxize` written to convert this (actually the full classification - only partially shown here) to a tree, using `class2tree`:

```
class.dat <- classification(c("Pseudomonas putida", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa","Enterobacter xiangfangensis","Salmonella enterica","Klebsiella pneumoniae"), db = 'ncbi')
taxize::class2tree(class.dat)
```

This does not show the ranks like in my hand made graph, that I need in my visualization:

[image]

---

**EDIT: dput of data**

```
structure(list(species = c("Pseudomonas putida", "Pseudomonas putida", 
"Pseudomonas putida", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", 
"Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Enterobacter xiangfangensis", "Enterobacter xiangfangensis", 
"Enterobacter xiangfangensis", "Salmonella enterica", "Salmonella enterica", 
"Salmonella enterica", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", 
"Klebsiella pneumoniae"), rank = c("family", "genus", "species", 
"family", "genus", "species", "family", "genus", "species", "family", 
"genus", "species", "family", "genus", "species"), value = c("Pseudomonadaceae", 
"Pseudomonas", "Pseudomonas putida", "Pseudomonadaceae", "Pseudomonas", 
"Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Enterobacteriaceae", "Enterobacter", 
"Enterobacter hormaechei", "Enterobacteriaceae", "Salmonella", 
"Salmonella enterica", "Enterobacteriaceae", "Klebsiella", "Klebsiella pneumoniae"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("species", 
"rank", "value"))
```

---

**EDIT: Response to @StupidWolf** 
I was able to convert the class.data to a dataframe and then into a parent-child dataframe to use it as input for the `ggraph`. The only thing left is having the xlabel, in this case the `interest` vector. However I'm not sure if that's possible in `ggraph`:

```
# Retreive data
class.dat <- classification(c("Pseudomonas putida", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa","Enterobacter xiangfangensis","Salmonella enterica","Klebsiella pneumoniae"), db = 'ncbi')

# Specify interest
interest <- c('superkingdom', 'phylum','class','order','genus','species')

# Convert to wide matrix
df2 <- bind_rows(class.dat, .id = "column_label") %>%
  dplyr::select(-id) %>% 
  filter(rank %in% interest) %>%
  spread(rank, name) %>%
  dplyr::select(-column_label) %>%
  dplyr::select(interest) %>% # we need the order
  as.matrix()

# Empty parent child matrix
parent.child <- matrix(nrow=0,ncol=2)

# Add data to parent child
for (i in 1:(ncol(df2)-1)){
  parent.child <- rbind(parent.child,df2[,c(i,i+1)])
}

# To dataframe and add colnmaes
parent.child <- as.data.frame(parent.child)
colnames(parent.child) <- c('from', 'to')

# Convert this to a ggraph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(parent.child)
ggraph(g,layout='dendrogram',circular=FALSE) + 
  geom_edge_link() + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label=names(V(g))),size=3,nudge_y=-0.1) + 
  scale_y_reverse(labels = interest)  + coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: can you add a `dput` of your data?

Comment: Of course! See the edit @ava

Comment: have a look at this thread here: https://www.gastonsanchez.com/visually-enforced/how-to/2014/06/29/Graph-from-dendrogram/ and the herein mentioned ape package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/ape.pdf. this might be of hlep

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out @Tjebo, but as far as I can see those produce similar plots as I could produce using `taxize` and thereby not explicitly show at what `rank` a species deviates

Answer (score 5):

Then we create a [hierarchical bundling](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/309-intro-to-hierarchical-edge-bundling.html)

```
d1 = data.frame(from="origin",to=c("Pseudomonadaceae","Enterobacteriaceae"))
d2 = data.frame(from=c("Pseudomonadaceae","Pseudomonadaceae","Enterobacteriaceae","Enterobacteriaceae","Enterobacteriaceae"),to=c("Pseudomonas","Pseudomonas","Enterobacter","Salmonella","Klebsiella"))
d3 = data.frame(from=c("Pseudomonas","Pseudomonas","Enterobacter","Salmonella","Klebsiella"),to=c("Pseudomonas putida","Pseudomonas aeruginosa","Enterobacter hormaechei","Salmonella enterica","Klebsiella pneumoniae"))

hierarchy <- rbind(d1, d2,d3)

vertices <- data.frame(name = unique(c(as.character(hierarchy$from), as.character(hierarchy$to))) )
```

Then we either plot them using igraph:

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame( hierarchy, vertices=vertices )
lay = layout.reingold.tilford(g) 
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(g, layout=-lay[, 2:1],vertex.label.cex=0.7,
vertex.size=1,edge.arrow.size= 0.4)
```

[image]

Or something like this in ggraph:

```
library(ggraph)
ggraph(g,layout='dendrogram',circular=FALSE) + 
geom_edge_link() + 
geom_node_label(aes(label=names(V(g))),size=2,nudge_y=-0.1) + 
scale_y_reverse()  + coord_flip() + theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Would suit my need if we could generate the variables (like `d1`, `d2`, and `d3`) generic rather than defining their structure by hand. I only gave an example dataset here but mine consists of 7 ranks and more species

Comment: I get the data from `class.dat <- classification(c("Pseudomonas putida", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa","Enterobacter xiangfangensis","Salmonella enterica","Klebsiella pneumoniae"), db = 'ncbi')` which already provides the dataframe.

Comment: Precisely my point. the output from classification(...) gives you a list, not a dataframe, and you did some conversion to get a data.frame. Do you mind trying to at least get a similar dataframe like d1,d2 and d3 from that?

Comment: for example, using your code above, if I do, t(sapply(class.dat,function(i)i[i$rank %in% c("family","genus"),"name"])), it's something similar to d2 right?

Comment: Found it! the default theme just hides it, so had to add `geom_classic()` and `scale_y_reverse(labels = rev(interest)`

Comment: Ok so if you find problems fitting the label in, one way is to use stringr::str_wrap(), so for example Vlab = str_wrap(names(V(g)),6) ;  then geom_node_label(aes(label=Vlab),size=3,nudge_y=-0.1)

Comment: Thankyou! was just searching for that haha

Answer (score 3):

Here's a graph based approach.

```
df = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, d$species), function(x){
    data.frame(rbind(c(x$value[match(c("family", "genus"), x$rank)], "root"),
                     c(x$value[match(c("genus", "species"), x$rank)], NA)),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))
df = unique(df)
rownames(df) = NULL
df

library(igraph)

g = graph.data.frame(df, directed = FALSE)

plot(g, layout = layout_as_tree(g, root = which(V(g)$name %in% sort(unique(df[,1][df[,3] == "root"])))))
```

and ggplot

```
d2 = d %>%
    spread(rank, value) %>%
    arrange(family, genus, species) %>%
    mutate(species = sapply(strsplit(species, " "), "[", 2),
           y3 = row_number(),
           grp = row_number(),
           y2 = ave(y3, genus, FUN = function(x) mean(x)),
           y1 = ave(y2, family, FUN = function(x) mean(x))) %>%
    gather(key, y, -family, -genus, -species, -grp) %>%
    mutate(x = as.numeric(factor(key, c("y1", "y2", "y3"))),
           lbl = case_when(
               key == "y1" ~ family,
               key == "y2" ~ genus,
               key == "y3" ~ species,
               TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
    arrange(x, y)

graphics.off()
ggplot(d2, aes(x, y, group = grp, label = lbl)) +
    geom_point(size = 2, shape = 21) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_text(hjust = "inward", vjust = "inward")
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an orgin here and the xl-lables as in my question example? besides this I like the results, although I would prefer something more generic instead of having to hardcode things like `"y1" ~ family` as my original data consists of 7 ranks rather than 3

Answer (score 3):

Great source for Phylogenetic trees with R by Prof.Guangchuang Yu:

https://yulab-smu.top/treedata-book/index.html

Heres my solution using ggtree:

```
# Packages :

if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("ggtree")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggtree)
library(treeio)
library(ape)
library(tidytree)
```

its better to use a dedicated Format when computing phylogenies
(for example  NEXUS)

```
# New Hampshire eXtended format :

treetext="(((P.putida:1[&&NHX:S=S],P.aerufgiosa:1[&&NHX:S=S:B=])
:1.3[&&NHX:D=Pseudomonas:S=G]):1[&&NHX:D=Pseudonadaceae:S=F],
((K.pneumoniae:1[&&NHX:]):1.3[&&NHX:D=Klebsiella],(S.enterica:1[&&NHX:])
:1.3[&&NHX:D=Salmonella],(E.xiangfangensis:1[&&NHX:]):1.3[&&NHX:D=Enterobacter])
:1[&&NHX:D=Enterobacteriaceae])
:1[&&NHX:D=Gammaproteobacteria];"


tree <- read.nhx(textConnection(treetext))

# Plot Stuff

d <- data.frame(.panel = c('Tree','Tree','Tree','Tree'), 
                lab = c("Class","Family" ,"Genus", "Species"), 
                x=c(0,1,2,3), y=-2)

p<-ggtree(tree) + geom_tiplab(offset = F) + 
  geom_label(aes(x=branch, label=S), fill='lightgreen') + 
  geom_label(aes(label=D), fill='lightblue') + coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') + 
  theme_tree2(plot.margin=margin(3, 3, 3, 3 ,"cm"), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())

p+geom_text(aes(label=lab), data=d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `ggplot2`:

```
# library
library(taxize)
library(ape)
library(ggdendro)
library(DECIPHER)
library(ggplot2)


# get data
class.dat <- classification(c("Pseudomonas putida", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa","Enterobacter xiangfangensis","Salmonella enterica","Klebsiella pneumoniae"), db = 'ncbi')

#make tree
taxize::class2tree(class.dat, varstep=FALSE,check=TRUE) -> tree

#adjust length
tree$phylo <- compute.brlen(tree$phylo, 10)

#convert tree to Dendrogram
ape::write.tree(tree$phylo, file = "./data/test", append = FALSE,
           digits = 10, tree.names = FALSE)
dend <- DECIPHER::ReadDendrogram("./data/test")

#get data from the dendrogram
dend_data <- dendro_data(dend, type = "rectangle")

# plot it with ggplot2
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(data=segment(dend_data), aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) + 
  geom_text(data=dend_data$labels, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label, hjust=0), size=3) +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_reverse(limits=c(20,-12),expand=c(0.1,1),breaks=c(20,10,0), labels=c("Family","Genus","Species")) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou @ava, I lik this solution but here is seems that they share the rank family which they do not (see my example tree), also I provided a simple example of my data and in reality I use almost all ranks: `Kingdom, phylum, class, order, family, genus, species`